# how to enter numeric value into textbox in webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to enter numeric value into  textbox in Selenium webdriver.
The code is below:  `sendKeys()` method is not working for numeric value, is there any alternative command for the integers.

```
@FindBy(id="toolbox-options-key")
private WebElement BillingRateTextBox;

    public void createNewBill(String billingRate)
    {
        BillingRateTextBox.sendKeys(10);
    }
```

Comment: Which version of browser and WebDriver do you use? Iy sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/q/23786319/2504101

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You have some formatting issues here, could you please fix them?

Comment: `sendkeys()` takes a String.

Comment: You could have just used `sendKeys("10")` instead of `sendKeys(10)`. How would system know what is `10`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to convert the Integer to String and pass them to `sendKeys` like this:

```
element.sendKeys(String.valueOf(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

running this:

`paris.FindElementByTag("input").SendKeys ("4")`

will APPEND 4 to the current input content.

```
paris.FindElementByTag("input").Clear
```

will put a 0 in the input

then SendKeys ("4") will work

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sendKeysINTByJS(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int attributeValue){
    JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+attributeValue+"');", netQtty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When an input box is of integer type, here is the solution for you to be able to pass integer values into this integer type input box:

```
{integer input box element ID}.Click();
{integer input box element ID}.SendKeys(""+99999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you can try if the input box is of integer type is:

```
@FindBy(id="toolbox-options-key")
private WebElement BillingRateTextBox;

    public void createNewBill(String billingRate)
    {
        BillingRateTextBox.sendKeys(int(10));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to enter numeric value into textbox in `webdriver`**
:

```
ExFactory_Price_per_Pack.sendKeys(String.valueOf(100));
```